# Modifying columnfamily metadata in Cassandra produces errors in datastax driver on server restart

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I'm seeing some very strange effects after modifying column metadata in a columnfamily after executing the following CQL query: `ALTER TABLE keyspace_name.table_name ADD column_name cql_type;`

I have a cluster of 4 nodes on two data centers (Cassandra version 2.0.9). I also have two application servers talking to the Cassandra cluster via the datastax java driver (version 2.0.4).

After executing this kind of query I see no abnormal behaviour whatsoever (no exceptions detected at all), however long I wait. But once I restart my application on one of the servers I immediately start seeing errors on the other server. What I mean by errors is that after getting my data into a ResultSet, I try to deserialize it row by row and get 'null' values or values from other columns instead of the ones I expect. After restarting the second server (the one that is getting the errors) everything gets back to normal.

I've tried investigating both the logs of datastax-agent and cassandra on both the servers but there is nothing to be found.

Is there a 'proper procedure' to altering the columnfamily? Does anyone have any idea as to what may be the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this issue using cqlsh?

Comment: No. Not able to reproduce because this setup is a production setup and I currently do not have an offline setup with more than one cassandra node or application server.

Comment: Are you still experiencing this? Have you run a repair on your keyspace?

Comment: Can't tell if I still have the problem because I haven't made any changes to my schema since. I've upgraded to Cassandra 2.0.9 and driver version 2.1.2 since though. I've run repairs to the keyspace before and after the issue.

Comment: K let me know if you see it again